# How can I use the Random.Range's answer to set as the max value into the same Random.Range until it reaches 1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

I want to create a script that generates a random number (between 1(min) and 9999(max)) and then I want the random number to become the new max for the same exact script.

Is there a way to create an equation or some sort of way to do this infinitely (until 1).

The only solution I have come up with is this:

```
private IEnumerator MyCoroutine()
{
    var a  = Random.Range(1, 9999 + 1);
    largeText.text = a.ToString();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    if (a > 1)
    {
        var b  = Random.Range(1, a + 1);
        largeText.text = b.ToString();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        if (b > 1)
        {
            //Then continues 'infinitely'
        }
    }
}
```

This is a solution, but I eventually run into the problem of having an extremely unwanted script.

Ofcourse I have the rest that I need with this script, and it does work, however I would like to know if there is an easier work around that doesn't involve me writing 1m lines of code.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar with C#, but are you familiar with recursion? Something like: private IEnumerator MyCoroutine(max_value)
{
    var a  = Random.Range(1, max_value);
    largeText.text = a.ToString();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    if (a > 1)
    {
        return MyCoroutine(a + 1);
    }
}

Comment: It totally depends that what you want to do with a script/function. There is a very good approach to this problem, which is ```recursion``` where function calls itself until some condition is meet. I've developed a function that meets your requirement. but I just want to know what excellently you want to do with this. because if you want ```1``` at the end you can just put ```1``` right.

Comment: @Ankit you are overseeing the behavior of this routine. It includes setting the value as a display text and waiting for 2 seconds .. simply returning `1` in the end is not even the goal and also recursion can be quite inefficient with Coroutines!

Comment: @derHugo yes, you are right. I've just went with the title I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply re-use the same variable instead of creating a new one for each "iteration" and use a `while` loop:

```
private IEnumerator MyCoroutine()
{
    var currentRandom = 9999;

    while(currentRandom > 1)
    {
        currentRandom = Random.Range(1, currentRandom + 1)
        largeText.text = currentRandom.ToString();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the goal is less lines of code, you can set `currentRandom = 10000` outside the loop, and remove the next 2 lines of code.

Comment: @Pluto good point, thanks and done ;) `9999` though since it gets increased by 1 within the loop ;)